# php import excel file error function str_replace

Tags: php

I have the code below, the purpose is to automatically add the product code.
For example, if the product code field is left blank, the default first product will be SP00001.
The next product will be SP00002...
The code still works fine with manually adding products. However, when I use the excel file to import data, I get the above code error.
The place where the product code runs is quite chaotic, only the first product is the code SP00001, then the full SP00002. The next time the code is entered, the codes are repeated a lot without knowing what's wrong. Thanks for your help.

```
 public function cms_save_product($data){
    $store_id = $this->auth['store_id'];
    $data['user_init'] = $this->auth['id'];
    if ($data['prd_code'] == '') {
        $code = $this->db
            ->select('prd_code')
            ->from('products')
            ->like('prd_code', 'SP')
            ->order_by('created desc')
            ->get()
            ->row_array();

        if(empty($code)){
            $data['prd_code'] = 'SP00001';
        }else{
            $max_code = (int)(str_replace('SP', '', $code['prd_code'])) + 1;
            if ($max_code < 10)
                $data['prd_code'] = 'SP0000' . ($max_code);
            else if ($max_code < 100)
                $data['prd_code'] = 'SP000' . ($max_code);
            else if ($max_code < 1000)
                $data['prd_code'] = 'SP00' . ($max_code);
            else if ($max_code < 10000)
                $data['prd_code'] = 'SP0' . ($max_code);
            else if ($max_code < 100000)
                $data['prd_code'] = 'SP' . ($max_code);
        }

    }
 $this->db->insert('products', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the record create date for ordering when looking for the greatest product code. If you are inserting many records in a loop while importing from a spreadsheet, and using something like `datetime` for your time format, this will cause your routine to generate the same code repeatedly until the next second ticks by. You should use something like:

```sql
SELECT MAX(prd_code) FROM products WHERE prd_code LIKE 'SP%'
```

for your query. This will ensure that you are always incrementing the highest product code.

You also have a problem where there is a maximum of 99999 product codes, which may be too low.

For the product code formatting, your logic can be greatly simplified by using [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad).

This will completely replace empty codes with SP00001, and handle formatting the code with the correct number of zeroes in order to match the desired length.

```php
$defaultCode = 'SP';

if (empty($code))
{
    $data['prd_code'] = $defaultCode;
}
else
{
    // Remove the SP prefix from the product code and cast to an int
    $numCode = (int)(str_replace('SP', '', $code['prd_code']));

    // Increment code
    $numCode++;

    /*
     * Set the pad length to either the size of the default code, or the
     * length of the stored product code plus 2 (for "SP" prefix), whichever is larger.
     * This ensures that the codes always begin with SP even if they are longer than expected.
     */
    $padLength = max(strlen($defaultCode), strlen($numCode) + 2);

    // Format the product code using the default code as a left pad
    $data['prd_code'] = str_pad($numCode, $padLength, $defaultCode, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I can't vote for you because I'm not qualified.
I'm looking to find out what is causing the error in my logic code. Can you point out what's wrong with them for me?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do in your logic - why are you incrementing the product code after changing it to in int? Are you really seeing an error from str_replace? If so, what are the values of $code['prd_code'] that are cauing that error?

Comment: I remove the "SP" prefix from the product snippet then +1 the values ​​after that.
The problem encountered when using an excel file with many lines, the following lines do not increase the product code value. If the product number is more than 10, the import into excel file is perfect. I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my logic.

Comment: Oh, OK, I see what you are doing and where the problem is. You are sorting by create date when querying for the highest code. If you are running in a loop, you will generate the same code over and over again for each second during execution. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I just found out that creating time at the same time will cause the last id to be wrong in php. thanks for your support.
Wish you a good day.